# iOS app Submit review to App Store failed

Tags: ios

When I submit an iOS app for review, we are getting a following message.

"An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review.If the issue persists please contact us"

It will be great if anyone have an idea about this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

There is a new checkbox. Be sure to tick it before submission.

[image]

After that, remove the current build, and add it again.

Then submit.

Comment: “Me too” is not an answer.

Comment: this did not work for me, I've set the advertising identifier settings (in my case set to Yes with all subflags selected), correctly saved the form, then selected the build, saved again, then pressed the submit for review button, and still getting the error An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review. "If the issue persists please contact us" I contacted Apple and still waiting for a response :-(

Comment: Thanks. Removed the current build and upload with different build number

Comment: where exactly is this form?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone getting this ambiguous error, you can use Developer tools to look at the actual HTTP request sent by Apple when you hit the button. That will have the real error rather than the generic message displayed on the UI.

[image]

It's a simple frontend fail, a bit ridiculous for a company as big as Apple..

Answer (score 0):

we just increased the version number (we had V.4.008.017) and we made it V.4.008.018 (but kept the same built binary). After restarting the browser, it worked for us.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios, the page is not been updated with the wrong alert.

It worked for me after I hit refresh in AppStoreconnect, status changed to Waiting for review

Answer (score -1):

Have you followed all iOS guidline, at what step are you getting this error message.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

You need to make sure you have followed all the guidline before submitting app for review as it will get reject if its not inline with their policy.

Share more detials about your issue

Comment: At the final step we are getting this message. when we hit on 'submit for review' button the message appears.
I have been following this guideline and uploaded 5 to 10 versions of the same app into the app store previously.